# Mercurial "submodule" inside a Git repository

Tags: git, mercurial

I'm about to start a new project, versioned with Git.

As with every new project, one of the first steps is usually to take all dependencies together. I usually use git submodules, so that I can update the dependencies easily.

But one of these dependencies is stored in a Mercurial repository.

Is there a way I can use this like a submodule? Is it safe to put a whole Mercurial repository in Git (doesn't sound like a good plan)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [git-hg](https://github.com/cosmin/git-hg) to check out the mercurial repository as a git repository and then add it as a submodule.

You won't be able push changes to the submodule, but you will be able to track them.